# \Locale::getDefault() returns always 'en' in Symfony deployed on the server

Tags: php, symfony

When I call `\Locale::getDefault()` In my Symfony2 application i get always `'en'` when on server.

In dev server is always ok.

In any case `$request->getLocale()` and `$request->getDefaultLocale()` return what is expected, i.e. `'fr'`, `'en'`, `'es'` depending on the route.

How can I influence `\Locale` over the application depending on my `Request` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable intl in your php.ini : `intl.default_locale = fr`.

And install intl for php : `sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl`